# BINDのzone設定が正常に読み込まれない

Tags: centos, dns

下記の様なZONE設定ファイルをtest.local、test.local.revとして作成してDNSサーバを構築しました。

しかしながらこれらのファイルを正常に読み込めていない、とjournalctlで見ると出てきます。
具体的にZONE設定の何が間違っているのか教えていただけませんでしょうか。

---

**test.local**

```
$TTL 86400

@   IN  SOA cent01.test.local. (
                    2020020501  ; serial
                    28800   ; refresh
                    14400   ; retry
                    3600000 ; expire
                    86400)  ; minimum
    IN  NS  cent01.test.local.
cent01.test.local.  IN A 1.4.7.31
cent02.test.local.  IN A 1.4.7.32
```

**test.local.rev**

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA  cent01.test.local. (
                    2020020501  ; serial
                    28800   ; refresh
                    14400   ; retry
                    3600000 ; expire
                    86400)  ; minimum
    IN NS   cent01.test.local.
1.4.7.31    IN PTR cent01.test.local
1.4.7.32    IN PTR cent02.test.local
```

追加
下記の設定に変更をした場合、うまくDNSサーバは動いているように見えます。named-checkzoneで確認をするとOKと出ます。root.test.local.を入れました。 しかしながら、別のPCからDNSサーバに対してnslookup 1.4.7.31を試すと ＊＊　server can't find 31.4.7.1.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN と表示されてしまいます。実際に存在するIPは1.4.7.31です。 逆にnslookup cent01.test.localを試すと名前解決は正しく出来ます。 尚、nslookup cent01を試すと下記のエラーが返ってきます。 **　server can't　find cent01：NXDOMAIN これは期待通りの動作だと思います。 どうして逆引きがうまく出来ないのか、教えていただけませんでしょうか？

---

**test.local**

```
$TTL 86400

@   IN  SOA cent01.test.local. root.test.local.(
                    2020020501  ; serial
                    28800   ; refresh
                    14400   ; retry
                    3600000 ; expire
                    86400)  ; minimum
    IN  NS  cent01.test.local.
cent01.test.local.  IN A 1.4.7.31
cent02.test.local.  IN A 1.4.7.32
```

**test.local.rev**

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA  cent01.test.local. root.test.local.(
                    2020020501  ; serial
                    28800   ; refresh
                    14400   ; retry
                    3600000 ; expire
                    86400)  ; minimum
    IN NS   cent01.test.local.
1.4.7.31    IN PTR cent01.test.local
1.4.7.32    IN PTR cent02.test.local
```

named.confは下記の通りです。

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 1.4.7.34; };
    #listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
    secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
    allow-query     { 1.4.7.0/24; };

    /* 
     - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
     - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable 
       recursion. 
     - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access 
       control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
       cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification 
       attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
       reduce such attack surface 
    */
    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "test.local" IN {
    type master;
    file "test.local";
};

zone "zone.rev" {
    type  master;
    file "test.local.rev";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Comment: `journalctl` での確認結果も (省略せずに) 質問文に含めておくと、回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: zoneファイルの情報は書かれていますが、そのzoneファイルを指定するnamed.confの設定はどのようになっていますか?

Answer (score 0):

`named-checkzone` で確認するとエラーになります。
`SOA` に不足があります。
「SOA  DNSサーバー  メールアドレス(@を.に置き換えたもの)」とする必要があります。

```
(例)
@   IN  SOA cent01.test.local. root.test.local. (
```

---

(2020/07/03 23:12) 追記

逆引きは `in-addr.arpa.` という特別なドメインを付けます。
IPv4アドレス **A.B.C.D** は **D.C.B.A.in-addr.arpa.** と逆順に対応します。
ネットワークアドレス 1.4.7.0/24 の zone は以下のように記述します。

```
(named.conf)
zone "7.4.1.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "test.local.rev";
};
```

また、test.local.rev は第4オクテットのみとするか、in-addr.arpa. まですべて記述します。

```
(test.local.rev)
31    IN PTR cent01.test.local.
32    IN PTR cent02.test.local.

    または
31.7.4.1.in-addr.arpa.    IN PTR cent01.test.local.
32.7.4.1.in-addr.arpa.    IN PTR cent02.test.local.
```

Comment: うまくDNSサーバは動いているように見えます。named-checkzoneで確認をするとOKと出ます。root.test.local.を入れました。
しかしながら、別のPCからDNSサーバに対してnslookup 1.4.7.31を試すと
＊＊　server can't find 31.4.7.1.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
と表示されてしまいます。実際に存在するIPは1.4.7.31です。
逆にnslookup cent01.test.localを試すと名前解決は正しく出来ます。
尚、nslookup cent01を試すと下記のエラーが返ってきます。
**　server can't　find cent01：NXDOMAIN
これは期待通りの動作だと思います。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 検証結果などは質問文を編集して追記ください。
正引きができて逆引きができないとのことなので、named.conf の zone 設定に問題がありそうです。